# Lagrange Multiplier Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I'm wondering why the Lagrange multiplier method only works when we assume that $\nabla g$ does not equal to $0$. I functionally understand why the algebra does not work out if this is that case, but could you provide a conceptual explanation for what this situation represents?

Comment: Do you understand the idea that underlies the method, i.e., that you’re looking for places where the gradients are parallel?

Comment: Yes, I do understand that principle.